# how to return cross value in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to return in JSON format the information on how many actors have acted in English language films, German language film, etc.

**For example**

I take take the `language_id` and check how many films have these languages. Then I check how many actors (`actor_id`) have every language version of these films.

I want to return something like the following:

```
{"English" : 123, #(different actors (by `actor_id`)
 "German" : 2456, 
 ... etc
}
```

**db**

```
film_actor    film           language
----------    ------         ---------
 actor_id     film_id        language_id
 film_id      title          name
              language_id
```

I know how to return how many films have every `language_id` but I don't know how to join, count and return more data.

```
@app.route('/langs')
def lang_list():
# query = '''
# SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM language 
# JOIN film USING (language_id) 
# GROUP by name

# '''
query = '''
SELECT name from language
JOIN film_actor using (film_id) 
GROUP by name

'''
args = ()
db = get_db()
data = db.execute(query, args).fetchall()
return_json= []
for i in data:
return_json.extend(list(i))

return_json = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(return_json)] * 2, fillvalue=""))

return jsonify(return_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of a language like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM film_actor 
JOIN film USING (film_id) 
JOIN language USING (language_id) 
WHERE name = "English";
```

Comment: But I need count how many actors plays in every language film categories

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) from language
join film using (language_id)
JOIN film_actor using (film_id) 
GROUP by name
```